# Wamp or Xamp not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, wamp

After reinstalling windows 10 my wamp or xamp don't work anymore.

I tried everything I've found on internet but nothing works.

There is no world wide web publishing service, no iss, tried other port.. Wamp icon stays red.

Also installed the VC++ packages

Really want to fix this..

Comment: What do the Apache logs say? Also, what is listening to your ports, for definite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: @user3428971, Did you try the solutions provided here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Windows 10 by default runs the service `World Wide Web Publishing Service` at startup of windows 10, which uses the port 80. Apache also will have to fight for port 80, and in the end, apache is left behind.

**Solution:**

1. Hit start button and type `services.msc` and enter.
2. Scroll down to the service name `World Wide Web Publishing Service` and double-click on it.
3. It should be running, hit the "stop" button, and change the startup type from `automatic` to `manual` and hit "Ok".
4. Now look for the wamp apache service in the same window and hit start. or you can start it the usual way.

*If you run any software that depends on `Microsoft IIS Web Server`, then you can make the service `World Wide Web Publishing Service` run again.*

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that the install of Windows 10 did not reinstate the Apache and MySQL services.

For WAMPServer all you need to do is, using the wampmanager menus :-

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
left click wampmanager -> Start All Services
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. It is working now. At first wamp64 didn't work.. After trying a lot of things on the wamp 32 bits I gave up and tried 64 again (after instaling lots of these vc++ files) and it worked.